# Create a matrix from dynamic dictionary

Tags: python, matrix, pandas

I want to create a matrix.

**Input**:

```
data = [
    {'a': 2, 'g': 1},
    {'p': 3, 'a': 5, 'cat': 4}
    ...
]
```

**Output**:

```
     a  p  cat  g
1st  2  0  0    1
2nd  5  3  4    0
```

**This is my code**. But I think it's not smart and **very slow** when data size huge.

Have any good ways to do this one?

Thank you.

```
data = [
    {'a': 2, 'g': 1},
    {'p': 3, 'a': 5, 'cat': 4}
]

### Get keyword map ###
key_map = set()
for row in data:
    key_map = key_map.union(set(row.keys()))

key_map = list(key_map)    # ['a', 'p', 'g', 'cat']

### Create matrix ###
result = []
for row in data:
    matrix = [0] * len(key_map)
    for k, v in row.iteritems():
        matrix[key_map.index(k)] = v
    result.append(matrix)

print result        

# [[2, 0, 0, 1], [5, 3, 4, 0]]
```

**Edited**

By @wwii advice. Use **[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)** looks good:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

result = DataFrame(data, index=range(len(data)))
print result.fillna(0, downcast=int).as_matrix().tolist()
# [[2, 0, 1, 0], [5, 4, 0, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the answer using the Pandas dataframes. However, my code should be a bit simpler than yours.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [5]: data = [{'a': 2, 'g': 1},{'p': 3, 'a': 5, 'cat': 4}]

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   a  cat   g   p
0  2  NaN   1 NaN
1  5    4 NaN   3

In [9]: df = df.fillna(0)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   a  cat  g  p
0  2    0  1  0
1  5    4  0  3
```

I did my coding in iPython, which I highly recommend!

To save to csv, just use an additional line of code:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use set comprehension to generate the `key_map`

```
key_map = list({data for row in data for data in row})
```

Comment: I tested this piece of code, it is indeed quite faster than mine, how?

Comment: @fyr0049 Its called [set comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Set_comprehension). Comprehensions are built in python's soul.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.  I couldn't get the columns in the order specified - it is limited by how the keys get ordered in the set, `key_map`.  It uses string formatting to line the data up - you can play around with the spacing to fit larger or smaller numbers.

```
# ordinal from
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576888-format-a-number-as-an-ordinal/
from ordinal import ordinal

data = [
    {'a': 2, 'g': 1},
    {'p': 3, 'a': 5, 'cat': 4}
]

### Get keyword map ###
key_map = set()
for row in data:
    key_map = key_map.union(set(row.keys()))

key_map = list(key_map)    # ['a', 'p', 'g', 'cat']

# strings to format the output
header = '{: >10}{: >8}{: >8}{: >8}'.format(*key_map)
line_fmt = '{: <8}{: >2}{: >8}{: >8}{: >8}'
print header

def ordered_data(d, keys):
    """Returns an ordered list of dictionary values.

    returns 0 if key not in d
    d --> dict
    keys --> list of keys
    returns list
    """
    return [d.get(key, 0) for key in keys]

for i, thing in enumerate(data):
    print line_fmt.format(ordinal(i+1), *ordered_data(thing, key_map))
```

**Output**

> > > ```
> > >          a       p       g     cat
> > > 1st      2       0       1       0
> > > 2nd      5       3       0       4
> > > ```

It might be worthwhile to dig into the Pandas docs and look at its [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) - it might make life easier.

Comment: Seems I might have misread the question, !again!.  I'll leave it up and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I will try to use Pandas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am a freshie in python, just suggestions that may be helpful hopefully:)

```
key_map = []
for row in data:
    key_map.extend(row.keys())
key_map = list(set(key_map))
```

you can change the middle part to this, which will save you some time to find the key_map

In your case `union` will at least scan through each row to find the different item.